# Uniform and own distribution (Python)

Tags: python, random

I have some statistics by age and I want to generate random values based on these statistics.
[Statistic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdJw1.png).

I want to select ranges based on their probability, and within the range, select a random value using uniform distribution.
For example, (25,35) - 37% and generate randomly... 33.
I have code:

```
import numpy as np
import random

range_age = [list(range(12, 18)), list(range(18, 25)), list(range(25, 35)), list(range(35, 45)),
             list(range(45, 55)), list(range(55, 70))]

age = random.choice(np.random.choice(range_age, p=[0.179, 0.257, 0.37, 0.109, 0.037, 0.048]))
print(age)
```

How can I get a value from a list with a uniform distribution? (Instead of this `random.choice`)
Or maybe you can use another way to generate a value based on statistics?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. Your code seems to do what you want, selecting a value with uniform distribution from a non-uniformly likely list of lists. What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: I think I can optimized my code, but I dont know how i can do this.